# PHP Inside tree

Tags: php

I have a table called quest:

```
id  name
1   First Quest
2   Second Quest
3   Third Quest
4   Fourth Quest
5   Fifth Quest
6   Sixth Quest
7   Seventh Quest
8   Eighth Quest
9   Ninth Quest
10  Tenth Quest
11  Eleventh Quest
12  Twelfth Quest
```

and a table called current_quests:

```
id  user
5   motoc
```

In my quests.php page I printed all twelve quests and assigned a link to each.
For the first one:
localhost/quests.php?quest=1
For the second one:
localhost/quests.php?quest=2
etc ...

Because in my current_quests table I have id 5 I want to make Fifth Quest bold in quests.php and 4,6 italic.

```
First Quest
Second Quest
Third Quest
*Fourth Quest*
**Fifth Quest**
*Sixth Quest*
Seventh Quest
Eighth Quest
Ninth Quest
Tenth Quest
Eleventh Quest
Twelfth Quest
```

What I want to do and I don't know how is when I insert another id in current_quest lets say id=6

```
id  user
5   motoc
6   motoc
```

I want Fifth and Sixth to became bold and 4 and 7 italic

```
First Quest
Second Quest
Third Quest
*Fourth Quest*
**Fifth Quest**
**Sixth Quest**
*Seventh Quest*
Eighth Quest
Ninth Quest
Tenth Quest
Eleventh Quest
Twelfth Quest
```

This is what I;ve tried but I'm sure that is bad.

```
function SelectQuest($i){
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM quests");
        $sth->execute();
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


switch ($row['id']) {
case $row['id'] == $i:
    print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'><b>$row[name]</b><br><br></a>";
    break 1;
case $row['id'] == $i-1:
    print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'><i>$row[name]</i><br><br></a>";
    break 1;
case $row['id'] == $i+1:
    print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'><i>$row[name]</i><br><br></a>";
    break 1;
default:
    print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'>$row[name]<br><br></a>";
}

}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM current_quest");            
    $sth->execute();   
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    if (isset($_GET['quest'])) {
        $item = $_GET['quest'];
    print "string";

    }elseif(isset($row['id'])){

    $quest = new Quests($dbh);
    $quest->SelectQuest($row['id']);       
    }
```

Sorry for the long post.
Here is a picture of what I want to achive.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try `case $i:` instead of `case TRUE:` or `case FALSE:`.  By having a boolean comparison in there, that is being evaluated.  [Read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for how to use the switch-case statement.  Also, you have a lot of *"I want"*, but not any "This is what is happening" and "This is what I've troubleshooted", so I have no idea if there is anything else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Get `current_quest` table data first. Parse received data and create array similar to this (create this entry for each row):

```
$isCurrentQuest[$YourQuestID] = true
```

Get `quest` table data and parse it like this:

```
if(!isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID] && (isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID - 1]) || isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID + 1])
{
   // Italic
}
else if(isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID])
{
   // Bold
}
else
{
   // Normal
}
```

(This code works correctly only if there is no empty ID between quests)

So your code would be:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM current_quest");            
$sth->execute();   
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $isCurrentQuest[$row['id']] = true
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM quests");
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if(!isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID] && (isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID - 1]) || isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID + 1])
    {
        print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'><i>$row[name]</i><br><br></a>";
    }
    else if(isset($isCurrentQuest[$QuestID])
    {
        print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'><b>$row[name]</b><br><br></a>";
    }
    else
    {
        print "<a href='quests.php?quest=$row[id]'>$row[name]<br><br></a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do this instead of fixing the switch-case statement?

Comment: Because it's easier and prettier that way

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use `LEFT JOIN` to receive all data you need from DB in one single query. Also receieved table data will contain all necessary data to render desired view.

```
$quests = array();

// performing single database query
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM quests
         LEFT JOIN current_quests ON current_quests.id = quest.id");
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  $quests[] = $row;

foreach($quests as $key => $quest)
{
  // use $quest['user'] or other current_quest field to find if quest is active
  if($quest['user'])
    echo "<a href='quests.php?quest=".$quest['id']."><b>$row['name']</b></a>";
  // mark neighbour item
  elseif((($key+1) < count($quests)) && $quest['user'])
    echo "<a href='quests.php?quest=".$quest['id']."><i>$row['name']</i></a>";
  // render ordinary item
  else
    echo "<a href='quests.php?quest=".$quest['id'].">$row[name]</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `case $i:` instead of `case TRUE:` or `case FALSE:`.

By having a boolean comparison in there, that is being evaluated. [Reading the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for how to use the switch-case statement might help.  You already gave it the value you want tested in the `switch()` part.  Each `case` is a value/case you want to test against to see if it matches, which is why you don't want a boolean.